# Mysql Avoiding Table to Table Relationship

Tags: mysql

I've got two tables...

Table "tags"

```
+---------+----------+
|  tag    |   id     |
+---------+----------+
|  nancy  |   902    |
+---------+----------+
|  fred   |   903    |
+---------+----------+
|  suzan  |   904    |
+---------+----------+
|  joe    |   905    |
+---------+----------+
```

and table tag to tag

```
+---------+----------+
|  tag_a  |   tag_b  |
+---------+----------+
|  903    |   902    |
+---------+----------+
|  905    |   903    |
+---------+----------+
|  902    |   904    |
+---------+----------+
|  904    |   905    |
+---------+----------+
```

I often scan the tag to tag relationships using an INNER JOIN statement with the "tag" table so that I can query who is related to "nancy".  I'm wondering how much better off I would have been better off just dumping the name of the tag into the tag to tag table rather than joining the tag table so that I can look for relationships based on the tag name. Is JOINING the table a huge performance hit?  My tag to tag table is in the 900k row range.  The tag table is around 30k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to store any meta-information about the tag, then you'll need a `tag` table anyway.  Adding a join does *potentially* increase the expense of the query a good deal.

In your case, I recommend you consider the following:

1. Use InnoDB
2. Change `id` to `TagString`
3. Place the actual tag in `TagString`
4. Create a foreign key to the `Tag` table, with cascading update/delete

In this way, you can group, filter, etc... on a single column, but if you need more info, you can join over to the `Tag` table (or whatever tables you need).

I ran into some serious performance problems with MySQL when we hit 80,000,000 tag records and were doing live joins to generate tag clouds on http://tagcloud.com ... Some caching really helped that, but still, it seemed like it was pushing the design limits of a relational database (in the normal form).  We would have been better off to use a different storage format that may be more expensive to write to, but faster to read from.

Comment: Gotta love getting getting a response from the developer of tagcloud.com :)  Thank you, I will look into this.  I have to read up on using foreign keys and InnoDB, but, I'm sensing this is certainly the right direction.

Comment: @HowardZoopaloopa: You remember tagcloud.com?  That's funny -- a long time ago.  I'd love to finish the re-launch and get it out there again.

Comment: PS. Thanks for bumping my rep to 20,000  :)